# MP3 to Audio converter under Fedora

Tags: fedora, audio, conversion

I have a folder that has ~10 mp3 files.

How can I convert them to "Audio format"? - I have an older CD player that doesn't handles MP3 files, only "Audio"....

I need a simple, GUI app for it (extra would be that the app automatically burns the converted MP3 files to a CD-ROM)

using Fedora 14/GNOME.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest k3b, but that is a KDE app.

For gnome: Try Brasero or GnomeBaker.

Comment: I choosed Brasero